# RewriteRule force SSL without WWW

Tags: ssl, rewrite

How can i force SSL without WWW

```
# SSL-FORCE
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Works but i can also open the site with www.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For domain: `www.example.com`, use:

```
# SSL-FORCE
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can also try:

```
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If port is not 443 *and* host name starts with `www`, perform rewrite. This will ensure that the secure version of your site is always served without `www.`